# How to run javascript functions from other website in iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I need to call onload in my index.html javascript function

```
connect("ws://agar.kuma.sk:500");
```

This function is exists on website http://agar.io/
Website http://agar.io is in iframe in my index.html

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="http://agar.io/" width=100% height=100% onload="connect('ws://agar.kuma.sk:500');"></iframe>
```

This is not working, because connect() is not exists in my index.html, how to i can call this function from iframe website ?

I trying also this code and is not working too.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://agar.io/'" onload="connect('ws://agar.kuma.sk:500');"/>
```

Comment: there is no way, unless they are same host and protocol..

Comment: do you control both domains? If not you can't do it, otherwise you need to adjust code inside iframe for cross domain communications

Comment: no agar.io is not my domain i have one kuma.sk

Comment: then you can't do what you are asking due to `same origin policy`

Comment: Can't my html send a command to meta refresh opened pages or iframe really ? :( I can just send it manually via the console, right?

Comment: What can i do with it ?

Comment: you can refresh it by changing the src of iframe...but you can not get inside a cross domain iframe